# Exception handling when writing data to disk

Tags: c++, file

I'm writing an application that takes a stream of records (like a student record) and writes all of them asynchronously to disk. There are billions of records, so I need to separate them into files of 4MB each. What does a file look like when an exception is thrown? If my record can not be written to disk, I will lose the data?

Comment: If you have that much data, and it's crucial to the operation of your system, then don't handle it yourself. Get a proper database instead.

Comment: You need to turn the problem inside out.  There will always be errors (software, hardware failure).  So you need to think: How do I design my application such that it is robust?  At some point building a robust application becomes more expensive than the cost of occasional failure, where this point is a critical decision.

Comment: "There are billions of records, so I need to separate them into files of 4MB each" - No, you don't.  You need an index if you're intending to search through your data; then it doesn't matter if it's one file or 5000.  Bear in mind hundreds of thousands of files in a directory will slow down the listing of it.  The other 2 questions you ask strongly suggest this project is too much for you (because they both have the answer "it depends") to take on with your current plan; so save yourself some pain and do what Someprogrammerdude suggested and get a 3rd party database.

Comment: sqlite has some very interesting documentation on how they go about their I/O, including how they deal with failures if I remember correctly. I suggest you go check it out (for example here: https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html). In short: it's complicated.

Comment: I'm developing a simple database, so I have to do it myself instead of use another database. Thank @Mat, that is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It is not only exceptions you must worry about. You must also consider write failures (which might or might not throw exceptions). If you are interested in ensuring the files are corrected formatted, you don't really need to concern yourself with enumerating precisely which errors can occur, because you will need to treat them all the same way. I recommend having the low-level writing code throw an exception if there is an error. Then your higher level code can treat all failures uniformly, as thrown exceptions.

It is possible to provide the minimum exception guarantee (not leaking resources or failing to maintain invariants) in that kind of output code, using RAII and `try`...`catch`.

To provide the strong guarantee, you could try to implement a roll-back operation to undo any write operations in the event of an exception. But that roll-back code must always work; it must never throw exceptions  (`noexcept`). That requirement  is impossible to satisfy, because any roll-back that does file IO operations can not be guaranteed to work.

But you can provide the strong guarantee by splitting the write operations in two. Change the file format so the start of the file has a header section, which records the number of records on the file. Then write to the file as follows.

1. Read the header to discover the number of records on the file.
2. Move forwards in the file to the location where the new record(s) should start. If the records are equal in length, this can be done with a seek operation.
3. Write the new records(s).
4. Commit (flush) those writes.
5. Seek back to the header.
6. Write the new record count into the header.
7. Commit that write.

Treat a failure of any write or commit as a failure of the whole operation. You have to assume that a successful write that happens to also automatically commit can never be followed by a commit operation (which should be a no-op)  that fails.  In practice that is probably a safe assumption except for remote file systems.

The down-side of this scheme is that writing to a file requires two write operations, two flush (commit) operations and two seek operations, which can be expensive if you have to do many writes. The flush operations in particular are expensive.

There are advanced techniques (such as journalling) that can provide high throughput despite many writes. RDBMSes and NoSQL data-stores use them. Rather than trying to implement them yourself, you would do better to use an existing third-party RDBMS or NoSQL data-store.